# How to add object into table using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/17674/

Once analyse the code in the above fiddle...What I am trying is when even i enter a item in text box ,the value should be added to the table.

I mean the output is:

```
       Item     |   Done
       Shopping |   checkbox with checked if status is true
       Cleaning |   checkbox based on status
```

If I add another item in the textbox,that must be added to table dynamically with checkbox false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your add function push the new item to the scope variable as its an array like given below

```
$scope.add=function(myvar)
            {
                $scope.tasks.push({item:myvar,status:false});
            }
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/divm/usabq8a3/2/) is the working fiddle

Comment: @NagaBhavani use this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/divm/usabq8a3/2/  the count function to show the correct remaining tasks is also updated in this

Comment: once analyse the code.If every chexkbox is checked the "remaining pending" should be eliminated and "all task are completed" should be displayed..But now even if all checkboxes are unchecked its showing all tasks are complted

Comment: Hey once i enter the text into box and click the button its adding to table but not clearing in the textbox

Comment: @NagaBhavani I wish you had figured this out yourself. http://jsfiddle.net/divm/usabq8a3/4/

Comment: I have done the same but slight change.Syntax is wrong...Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

it is easy  just put      `$scope.tasks.push({item:myvar,status:false});`                                   into **add** function .